# javascript: изменить один элемент массива и передать весь массив... в одной строке

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

в react состояния вне конструктора задаются через использование функции `setState`:

```
setState({
    arr: [1, 2, 3]
});
```

Но мне надо изменить лишь один элемент в массиве

Как это корректнее сделать:

Через

```
this.state.arr[2] = 3;
```

получаю ворнинг:

```
Line 66:13:  Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()  react/no-direct-mutation-state
```

Хотелось бы всё делать по правильному и покрасивее :)

Что современная наука может предложить?

```
let tmp = this.state.arr;
tmp[2] = 3;
setState({
    arr: tmp
});
```

как-то криво на мой взгляд, а просто отключить этот ворнинг как-то неправильно

Comment: используйте колббек в `useState((prevState)=>{})` смотрите примечание в [документации](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял вы работаете с классовыми компонентами.

Как правильно предложил **xydope** можно использовать вариант с коллбэком.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    [prevState.arr[2]]: 3,
}));
```

Как альтернатива если у вас установлен [**Lodash**](https://lodash.com/) можно использовать [**cloneDeep**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) .

```
import head from "lodash/head";
import cloneDeep from "lodash/cloneDeep";
//..

const clonedStateArray = cloneDeep(this.state.arr);

head(clonedStateArray) = 3;

this.setState(prevState => ({ arr: clonedStateArray }));
```

Про мутирующие методы массивов я думаю вы в курсе, но все же оставлю [**тут**](https://doesitmutate.xyz/) ссылку может кто не знает.